# PeopleSoft Query - finding people without leave type

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm working with PeopleSoft's query manager and I'm having trouble creating a report that will find all active employees who do not have a certain leave type.

I have the two tables (Employees - Non terminated Employees and Leave_Accrual-EE). They are left outer joined. The field in question is PLAN_TYPE. Now, I've tried creating a filter to pull in all employees who do not have plan type 54.  The criteria is B.PLAN_TYPE not equal to 54, but that still brings up everyone, it just doesn't bring up the row for 54.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious - maybe I have to create a subquery? If so, I have never done this in PeopleSoft.

Anyone have any advice?

Original SQL screenshot.

[image]

UPDATED

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less of a PeopleSoft question, and more of a SQL question.

The problem you have been running into is that you are doing a per-row filter and excluding only rows that have the undesirable code.

What you need to do instead is exclude all rows for a user that has the undesirable code in any row.

This can be done with a NOT IN or NOT EXISTS query.
e.g.

```
SELECT EMPLID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE 
   EMPLID NOT IN 
   (
      SELECT EMPLID 
      FROM TABLE1 
      WHERE CODE = 123
   )
/
```

alternately

```
SELECT A.EMPLID
FROM TABLE1 A
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT B.EMPLID 
      FROM TABLE1 B
      WHERE 
         B.CODE = 123
         AND B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
   )
/
```

See this SQL Fiddle example to test out the SQL:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b0f6/7

To do this in PS Query, you could do this by adding a criteria with a subquery on the right side of the equivalence.

[image: add subquery]

[image: compare using NOT EXISTS or maybe NOT IN]

Here is some documentation:

[Home > PeopleSoft PeopleTools 8.53 > PeopleSoft Query > Working with Subqueries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57990_01/pt853pbh2/eng/pt/tpsq/task_WorkingwithSubqueries-c0754c.html#topofpage)

Comment: I feel like you've given me the right track, but I'm still doing something wrong. On the top level of the query, I have: AND A.EMPLID - Empl ID *not in list* Subquery. Then in the Subquery I have: C.Plan_Type - Plan Type equal to 54. 

I would think that I'm saying find the Empl ID that *are not in the list* of plan_type 54, but it just seems to pull everyone and every plan type (including 54).

Comment: do you have access to the View SQL tab? What does it show?

Comment: I've added a picture of it. I also took out my operatorID.

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles - Looking at [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dukv3.png), your NOT IN query should select the same field as your outer query. 
i.e. `A.EMPLID not in (SELECT C.EMPLID FROM ...)` but at present you aren't selecting the same field inside as your are filtering outside 
i.e. `A.EMPLID not in (SELECT C.PLAN_TYPE ...)`

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time. I've updated the script, and it whittled down the number of records considerably, it still doesn't appear to be getting the right information. The first person on the list HAS the plan 54. So I have no idea what the report is pulling.

Comment: IF I change the subquery criteria (I got into the subquery then the criteria tab) it shows: C.Plan_Type equal to 54. If I change that to C.Plan_type not equal to 54 there are *less records* but it appears to actually bring in people IN plan 54 and some not in.