# PeopleSoft Subquery

Tags: sql, powerquery, peoplesoft

I'm still having difficulties creating a subquery that will capture employees without plan type 54. I've made some progress, realizing that I wasn't looking at the right table, but I've hit a set back.

Here's the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154638/peoplesoft-query-finding-people-without-leave-type/48160176#48160176):

The two tables are: LEAVE_PLAN - EE and EMPLOYEES. I'm trying to find all employees who do not have plan type '54'.

When I run the query that I created, I get this error:

A SQL error occurred. Please consult your system log for details.
Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=8601, Message=[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL (50,380)

The SQL is below:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Relatively straightforward error. One of your subqueries is returning more than 1 row. You are using it in a comparison. The engine can't compare multiple values to 1 and output 1 result. Run your subqueries (those 3 in your WHERE clauses) and see which one is returning multiple records. Then modify the subquery accordingly.

Comment: Seems unrelated to powerquery?

Comment: I had to recreate the query and whatever I did, fixed the issue.That said, what do you mean, Mike?